# What should the D&D Tags be without an ampersand (&)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that the tags don't allow the ampersand.  This leaves the tag D&D4 as `dd4`.  What should we label D&D as?

- `dand`
- `dungeons-and-dragons`
- `d-and-d`
- Your suggestion here!

**Edit:** In response to [Robert's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-the-dd-tags-be-without-an-ampersand/6#6) we would obviously convert the version tags to the same format.

Comment: Doing markup like && and \& doesn't work.  Is there a meta-tagging discussion somewhere that tells how to put amps in a tag?

Comment: I found the answer.  See the comments in Erik's answer.

Comment: the original question created a [dd] tag that was edited away. [dd] is now floating, questionless, on meta.rpg...

Comment: dd4.0, dd3.0, d3.5, etc works for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

DnD perhaps?

...........

Comment: And use DnD4, DnD3.5, etc. for things that are specific to each version.

Comment: I like the [DnD] option.  It's easier than [D-and-D] and clearer than [dd].  Special characters (&, !, #, /) are barred from titles and tags because they can't be put into a URL.  The system dynamically builds URLs based on what you are trying to do.  For instance, check out the URL when you click on a tag...

Comment: +1 on DnD, instead of DD. It seems more natural, as when one says "D&D", it's pronounced "DnD".

Comment: Except that tags *don't* display capitalized. Is **[dnd]** as nice/clear?

Comment: I'd prefer DnD myself.

Why don't we just see what rises to the top and then promote that?

DD now makes me think of bras thanks to @Richard!

Comment: Since tags are always lowercased, [dnd] makes me think of "Do Not Disturb" right away no matter what context it's used in.  It's also not as discoverable to new users since [d&d] will autocomplete to [dd] when they're asking questions.

Comment: Aha. I think the autocomplete issue is the clincher for me. I don't mind [dnd], but if a new user will get [dd] when they type [d&d], that's going to be easier for them.

Comment: This answer seems to be the will of the people we will proceed down this path.

Comment: We could always create a [dd-perhaps-you-meant-dnd-instead] tag.

Answer (score 6):

I already see a lot of version-specific questions tagged [dd3.5] [dd4.0], etc.

So to stay consistent, I would suggesting sticking to [dd], in the generic case.

Comment: I like the way it is currently.

Comment: This is working quite well. Haven't seen much\any mis-tagging issues.

Comment: While it is working quite well, it can be easily changed (moderator retagging tools).  Still makes sense to wait and see I think.

Answer (score 2):

dd
odd
add1
add2
dd3e
dd4e
holmes
ddbx
ddbemci

those should cover the major variants.

Answer (score 1):

I actually am OK with dd -- does it conflict with anything?

Comment: It makes me think of a bra size more than an RPG.

Comment: @Richard Thank you for firmly corrupting that tag for me.

Comment: Despite certain unfounded chat accusations, I have not ever edited [dnd] to [dd]! I don't think I have, anyhow. My personal crusade is [dm] -> [gm]. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using full names when possible for search purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late since the dd, dd3.0 etc. tags are well ensconced. However, I still think dnd, dnd3.0 etc. are better.

As a data point, #dnd is the well-known hash-tag for D&D discussion on Twitter. It does occasionally have comical overlap with the Do Not Disturb people, though. =D